# Debugging compound statements

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Let's say I have a line of code like this (as an example)

```
HttpUtility.DecodeUrl(HttpUtility.EncodeHtml(getSomeText()));
```

When I step through the code, is there way in Visual Studio to find out what getSomeText() returned and then what EncodeHtml returned and finally what DecodeUrl returned without having to do this:

```
string someText = getSomeText();
string encodeHtml = HttpUtility.EncodeHtml(someText);
string DecodeUrl = Http.Utility.DecodeUrl(encodeHtml);
```

Thanks all.

Comment: No.  But [read this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If compound statements aren't doing what you expect, to me this indicates that your compound statements are too complex, and probably should be broken down anyway. However, that was not your question.

Why don't you just step into getSomeText, step through until you get to the return, and see what it returns?

Comment: I agree with your statement.  However, if I breakout a compound statement for debugging....I'm not putting it back into the compound form anymore.  Which in that case, three vars were wasted.  No?

Comment: (1) Variables are cheap; brain time is expensive. (2) since each of those variables cease to be used before the next one is needed, they will probably use the same space. And (3), even if you don't give it a variable name, the values will still need to be stored somewhere, even in the compound statements.

Comment: Accepted as answer.  As former Perl programmer, I love "tight" code.

Comment: Ditto (both perl & tight code); however, there has to be a balance. Usually, if I find I need to break it apart to do debugging, this is an indicator that it needs to be broken apart. Otherwise, I often do my debugging in the appropriate sub-function (`getSomeText()` in your example)